# Github Wiki as a subfolder of the main project

Tags: github

We have a project self-hosted on our Phabricator instance. I made a mirror of the project on GitHub.

The project has a subfolder called `docs` that contains the documentation in Markdown.

If the project was hosted on Github, I would add the wiki as a submodule of the main project -- however, the project is hosted on Phabricator and I do not want anything on the Phabricator repo to link to GitHub.

How can I tell Github to use the `docs/` folder for the wiki, without any modification needed to the Phabricator repo?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-or-editing-wiki-pages/#adding-or-editing-wiki-pages-locally) from GitHub's documentation would indicate that GitHub wiki's are stored in a separate repository which I would think means this is not possible.